# Calling a function that has await keyword in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

```
class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I know that await will waits the execution till the promise resolves. Here we are calling bootstrapAsync function, that have await keyword, in the constructor so does it mean the constructor execution will wait till the promise resolves?

Comment: perhaps the question is: what's `async` in a function?

Comment: No, the constructor will finish before the promise settles; it *doesn't* `await` the result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, is that a special case for constructor function or all functions will do that.

Comment: All functions; the function you're calling being async just means it returns a promise, it doesn't magically make the process synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

What you're using is [react-nagivation](/questions/tagged/react-nagivation) and the `AuthLoader` is a "switch loader component" which utilizes the [SwitchStackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html). This is a screen where you want to spend as ***little*** time as possible on.

Why? Well because there is no content to show except for an indefinite progress bar. That's the reason why bootstrap async is called in the constructor.

> the constructor execution will wait till the promise resolves?

No, it won't. The idea with the switch loader is to load the current state of your app and redirect (aka `switch`) to the correct route.

That's why it doesn't matter if the screen is mounted or not, and that is why the bootstrapAsync is called in the constructor since that is the earliest it can be called.

Answer (score 0):

It won't wait, because the constructor function is not an async function and you don't have an await before the function call.

In order to wait until the function ends to execute your code, you will need to use `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. To be sure Promise resolved until constructor returns value you should actually return the Promise from the constructor and await it.

```
class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
    // async can't be used with constructor, so we just return Promise
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            _bootstrapAsync().then(() => resolve(this))
        })
    }

    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    // async function returns Promise
    _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
       const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

       // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
       // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
       this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
    };

    // Render any loading content that you like here
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator />
                <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
// construct the object in async function
const instance = await new AuthLoadingScreen()
```

To be sure it works here is a sample:

```
(async () => {
    class foo {
        constructor() {
            console.log(2)
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this)).then(() => console.log(3))
        }
    }

    console.log(1)

    const b = await new foo()

    console.log(4)
})()
```

1 2 3 4 is the output

Comment: You do you realize that this is react-native and what you're advising should **not** be done in this situation ?

Comment: Just posted an answer for a common situation with async constructor.

Comment: This is highly not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should move the `this._bootstrapAsync()` method from `constructor` to `componentDidMount()` life-circle method.

In addition, there are many ways to authorize user.The best practice is creating a Routing component for private route. [Example](https://medium.com/@tomlarge/private-routes-with-react-router-dom-28e9f40c7146)